# Import file in Matlab with headers

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have following data

```
Month   High     Low    Average
    1   45.36   33.84   39.6
    2   50.87   35.98   43.43
    3   56.05   38.55   47.3
    4   60.49   41.36   50.92
    5   67.17   46.92   57.05
    6   73.82   52.8    63.31
    7   79.72   56.43   68.07
    8   80.14   56.79   68.47
    9   74.54   51.83   63.18
    10  64.08   44.95   54.52
    11  52.66   39.54   46.1
    12  45.59   34.75   40.17
```

I know that I need the function fprintf to import a file which contains headers. We have 4 columns and  12 rows, so how can I use the fprintf function or which function should I use to import data successfully? There is [this code](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/MATLAB/plotting/examples/readColData.m), but I am not sure if it is reliable. Can I use something from Matlab itself?

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html  (I have no idea where you got `fprintf` from, it is for exporting/writing files, not importing/reading them)

Comment: What format is your data on? .txt, .xlsx, .csv ...?

Comment: .txt ,how can i use this formulas?

Comment: After 630 questions (a lot of which have been edited by others) you should really know how to properly capitalize your posts. And of course a ["thanks in advance" should be left out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `fscanf` for files and `sscanf` for strings. The syntax is similar to that of `fprintf` you're familiar with. [The matlab documentation provides a comprehensive set of examples to get you started.](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html)

Less flexible, but sufficient for your use would probably be [`dlmread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).

assuming your data is in `data.txt` and you'd like to skip the first row (as it's the header) do:

```
>> x = dlmread('data.txt', '', 1, 0)

x =

    1.0000   45.3600   33.8400   39.6000
    2.0000   50.8700   35.9800   43.4300
    3.0000   56.0500   38.5500   47.3000
    4.0000   60.4900   41.3600   50.9200
    5.0000   67.1700   46.9200   57.0500
    6.0000   73.8200   52.8000   63.3100
    7.0000   79.7200   56.4300   68.0700
    8.0000   80.1400   56.7900   68.4700
    9.0000   74.5400   51.8300   63.1800
   10.0000   64.0800   44.9500   54.5200
   11.0000   52.6600   39.5400   46.1000
   12.0000   45.5900   34.7500   40.1700
```

--edit--
from the docs:

> dlmread(filename, delimiter, R, C) reads data whose upper left corner
>   is at row R and column C in the file, using the specified delimiter.
>   The filename input is a string enclosed in single quotes. 
>   Values R and C are zero-based, so that R=0, C=0 specifies the first
>   value in the file.

Now as we would like to use the default delimiter (any number of spaces), but must provide one as we're also providing `R`ow and `C`ol arguments, we provide an empty string.

Comment: i need  by example to understand better

Comment: How/why would you like to include the headers? I'm assuming the headers will always be the same. But say you'd like to include them. Matlab wouldn't be able to present them to you like an array the same way it does now. Because now it returns you a rectangular array of numbers, but the headers aren't numbers. (there are cell arrays and datamatrices, but those would make everything a lot more complicated..)

Comment: can it be used in .dat type of files?

Comment: ``dat`` is short for data. It's not really a specification like ``jpeg`` or ``mkv``. ``dlmread`` works as long as you can open the file in notepad and the file has the format you specified in your initial question. The name doesn't matter, only the contents do.

Comment: ok thank you,but this command makes mistake like  this Error using dlmread (line 138)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 1u) ==> Month   High     Low    Average\n

Comment: If you open the file in notepad. At which line do the numbers start? The number ``1`` in my example means ``dlmread`` should start after the first line (as specified in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `importdata`.  It might be a bit slower but it's pretty good at figuring out what the header is and omitting it.